# MockitoJUnitRunner is deprecated

Tags: java, mockito, deprecated

I'm trying to make a unit test with `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock`.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProblemDefinitionTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ProblemDefinition problemDefinition;

    @Mock
    Matrix matrixMock;    

    @Test
    public void sanityCheck() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(problemDefinition);
        Assert.assertNotNull(matrixMock);
    }
}
```

When I don't include the `@RunWith` annotation, the test fails. But

> The type MockitoJUnitRunner is deprecated

I'm using Mockito 2.6.9. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

[`org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) is now indeed deprecated, you are supposed to use [`org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) instead. As you can see only the package name has changed, the simple name of the class is still **`MockitoJUnitRunner`**.

Excerpt from the javadoc of `org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner`:

> Moved to [`MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html), this class will be removed with
>   Mockito 3

Comment: And I did wonder why mine is NOT deprecated ;-)

Answer (score 12):

You can try this:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Because you add `@Before` annotation, Your mock objects can be new and recorded many times, and in all test you can give objects new properties. But, if you want one time record behavior for mock object please add `@BeforeCLass`

Answer (score 6):

There is also a `@Rule` option:

```
@Rule 
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
@get:Rule
var rule = MockitoJUnit.rule()
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix this when I updated the dependencies to the latest versions in my case:

```
def mockito_version = '2.28.2'

// For local unit tests on your development machine
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito_version"

// For instrumentation tests on Android devices and emulators
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito_version"
```

Then I changed the imports by the replace command (Mac: cmd+Shift+R Windows: Ctrl+Shift+R)
from

```
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

to

```
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try importing the following:

```
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

Also, if you are using ***Eclipse***, just press **Ctrl + Shift + O** and it will auto import it.

Answer (score 0):

JunitRunner worked, thank you all