# Intellij doesn't recognise Mockito class as Test class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

i use IntellJ Ultimate and have problems to run a Mockito test class.

If I use a class like that

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class FactoryTest {
    @Test
    void createEntry() {
    }

}
```

I can straight "run" this class.

If I have this:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

// @RunWith attaches a runner with the test class to initialize the test data
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MathApplicationTester {

   //@InjectMocks annotation is used to create and inject the mock object
   @InjectMocks 
   MathApplication mathApplication = new MathApplication();

   //@Mock annotation is used to create the mock object to be injected
   @Mock
   CalculatorService calcService;

   @Test
   public void testAdd(){
      //add the behavior of calc service to add two numbers
      when(calcService.add(10.0,20.0)).thenReturn(30.00);

      //test the add functionality
      Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.add(10.0, 20.0),30.0,0);
   }
}
```

I have to create another class before and run it which seems not correct to me because in that tutorial there is nothing written about an exlucisv class which starts the test http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#testing-with-mock-objects

```
    public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(MathApplicationTester.class);

        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>1</groupId>
    <artifactId>2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>1</groupId>
            <artifactId>2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MockitoJUnitRunner` is [already deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909538/mockitojunitrunner-is-deprecated).

After getting rid of it, you can initialize your mocks with a `@Before`-annotated method:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```